# BindBase only binds immediate ancestors

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a similar situation to this in my code, where I have a class that descends from two ancestor abstract classes, like so:

```
BaseAbstractClassExample <|-- AbstractClassExample <|-- ConcreteClassExample
```

I did this to extend an abstract class defined in the framework. While I'm aware there are other design patterns that might be better suited to my situation, I'm curious why this convention-based binding doesn't work.

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions; 

public abstract class BaseAbstractClassExample
{
    public abstract int Number { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClassExample : BaseAbstractClassExample
{
    public abstract bool Flag { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteClassExample : AbstractClassExample
{
    public override int Number { get; set; }
    public override bool Flag { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Concrete_classes_are_bound_to_grandfathers()
{
    kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                        .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<BaseAbstractClassExample>()                            
                        .BindBase());

    AssertCanResolveBindingToType<ConcreteClassExample, ConcreteClassExample>(); // pass
    AssertCanResolveBindingToType<AbstractClassExample, ConcreteClassExample>(); // pass
    AssertCanResolveBindingToType<BaseAbstractClassExample, ConcreteClassExample>(); // fail
}
```

Here's the assert method I wrote to test bindings, which is tangential to my question.

```
private static void AssertCanResolveBindingToType<TRequestedType, TExpectedType>(params IParameter[] constructorParameters)
    {
        if (!typeof(TRequestedType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TExpectedType)))
            Assert.Fail("{0} is not assignable from {1}, this binding wouldn't work anyway", typeof(TRequestedType), typeof(TExpectedType));

        IEnumerable<TRequestedType> result = kernel.GetAll<TRequestedType>(constructorParameters);
        var requestedTypes = result as TRequestedType[] ?? result.ToArray();
        Assert.IsTrue(requestedTypes.Any(), "There are no bindings for {0} at all", typeof (TRequestedType));
        Assert.IsTrue(requestedTypes.OfType<TExpectedType>().Any(),
                      "There are no bindings for {0} of the expected type {1}, bound types are: {2}", 
                      typeof (TRequestedType), typeof (TExpectedType),
                      string.Join(", ", requestedTypes.Select(x => x.GetType().ToString()).Distinct()));
    }
```

When I try the unit test above, it asserts with my custom message "There are no bindings for BaseAbstractClassExample at all", which shows that the binding to `AbstractClassExample` is working as expected, but not the one to `BaseAbstractClassExample`.

*Edit: I wrote a method `BindAllBaseClasses()` that provides this functionality. I submitted a pull request and it was approved, so this functionality is now available in the [Ninject extensions conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions)  library.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. When you use SelectAllClasses it doesn't select Abstract classes because the filter used is the following:

```
  public IJoinFilterWhereExcludeIncludeBindSyntax SelectAllClasses()
        {
            return this.SelectTypes(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract);
        }
```

Try to use

```
 public IJoinFilterWhereExcludeIncludeBindSyntax SelectAllIncludingAbstractClasses()
        {
            return this.SelectTypes(t => t.IsClass);
        }
```

Although this doesn't explain to me why you are able to resolve AbstractClassExample. This might be a bug. Do you mind raising an issue on the convention extension? Another cause could be that the BaseBindingGenerator doesn't include abstract classes.

Comment: Not at all, happy to raise an issue. I wasn't sure it was one, to be honest. To me, the extension's documentation isn't entirely straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel explained `SelectAllClasses()` selects all classes that are not abstract. It makes no sense to select abstract classes because it is not possible to create an instance of them.

So in your case it selects `ConcreteClassExample`.

Then `BindBase()` tells that a binding of the base class to the selected class shall be added. In your case it is:

```
Bind<AbstractClassExample>().To<ConcreteClassExample>();
```

Now you can resolve `AbstractClassExample` because there is a binding and `ConcreteClassExample` because it is self bindabel and Ninject will create an implicit self binding even if there is no configured one.

You can't resolve `BaseAbstractClassExample` because there is neither a binding for it nor is it self bindable because it is abstract.

Comment: Thank you. I think what I'm after is an analogous operation to `BindAllInterfaces()` but for abstract classes. It seems that `BindBase() ` behaves more like `BindDefaultInterface()` in that it doesn't walk the inheritance tree.